# Link a C++/CLI DLL to a Qt C++ application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, c++-cli, clr

There is a dynamic library **mylib.dll** written in C++ and compiled with Visual Studio, with common language runtime (/clr) support, that exports a function:

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) exported_func();
```

And there is a Qt C++ application that links to this library. **mylib.lib** is added to the project's .pro file.

```
LIBS += mylib.lib
```

**Problem:** Application compiles well. But just on start of run, it crashes without even entering `main` function. Path to mylib.dll is added to PATH environment variable, and is loaded just before the crash.

Crash message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x000007FEE18831E7 in app.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x000007FEE18831E7.
```

No more information, even in call stack.

Why?

Comment: I'm fairly sure a C++/CLI module cannot be referenced from a native C++ module. It is possible the other way around. You can however invoke it with some nasty COM interop though.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, other than calling that exported function?

Comment: Why do you compile it with CLR support if it uses native (C++) only?

Comment: @vahancho It is not native only. I simplified it down to the subject. It is actually a wrapper around a .Net assembly.

Comment: @Neijwiert But I did link to a VC++ native project for many times without problems. Problem arised when native C++ code is in Qt.

Comment: It will help us if you explain why you need managed code. That way we might avoid [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying. Are you saying you were able to reference and use a C++/CLI module from a native C++ in the past?

Comment: @Neijwiert What I want is calling a method from a .net assembly written in C# language. I used a C++/CLI as a wrapper around it.

Comment: C++/CLI is meant for native interop only. Not the other way around. You can call managed methods from unmanaged code using COM interop. You have to mark the method for COM. Not sure what steps are required but you definetely don't need/should use C++/CLI if you only call 1 method.

Comment: @Neijwiert yes but only if the calling application is written directly in Visual Studio (with default compiler options that it assigns when creating a new project. But with Qt, I cannot do that. I think Qt runs cl.exe with different compiler options

Comment: If you really need to call multiple methods/classes or stuff you should consider using a shared native library with which your QT library exposes itself to the managed side and vice-versa.

Comment: You can compile your C# module separately from QT.

Comment: This is a quite common thing to do these days. My best guess is you didn't include the .lib produced by the C++/CLI project as linker input in your native project(s). There should be no need to update PATH.

Comment: @Neijwiert you say creating a wrapper around a .net assembly as C++/CLI to be consumed by Qt C++ or even simple C++ is not recommendd?

Comment: @downhillFromHere But I did include the lib file as a linker input. I said that in the question

Comment: Wrapper around a .net assembly as C++/CLI AND a shared native C++ library that is consumed by QT and the C++/CLI assembly. Start the domain inside the QT application (I'm assuming that is where you are originating from) and call some arbitrary init function that connects the two together.

Comment: @downhillFromHere C++/CLI modules cannot be linked to native C++ modules as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @downhillFromHere But I did that. I will write a sample for you later